# getSignedUrl - how to upload large files from a web browser?

Tags: google-chrome, file-upload, streaming, google-cloud-storage

If I get an URL with `getSignedUrl`, that allows upload to Google Cloud Storage, how can I use it to upload large files from a web browser (Chrome)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it can't be done yet.

http://w3c-test.org/fetch/api/basic/request-upload.any.html